# Dependency is disappeared after changing scope to runtime

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

I need to use some jar dependency in runtime scope, but after changing it in pom.xml this dependency disappeared from dependency list. Classes from this dependency is used during compiling and running, so i need this dependency to be at runtime scope.

Answer (score 3):

If You use the classes from dependency in compilation, You need "compile" scope. Runtime dependency is not in compile classpath.

Comment: So, is it possible to use dependency during compilation and runtime?

Comment: yes it is. "compile" scope dependencies are in compilation and runtime classpathes

Comment: But why i got a "NoClassDefFound" exception while trying to run a class from compiled jar?

Comment: How are you running your program?

Comment: java -cp "CLASSPATH" Application -args

Comment: Basically what i am trying to do is to run some java class that contains come dependencies from other jar module.

Comment: Still not clear what is the actual problem. 
When you set the scope to runtime the program compiles but doesn't start, does it?

Comment: @psed Try to use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html). Run program with `mvn exec:java`.

Answer (score 2):

If you need classes from your dependency while compiling then you should use `compile` scope, which is the default.

In order to run your application you need all of the dependent jars to be on the classpath. You can use Maven in various ways to achieve that, but the correct scope is still `compile`.

Answer (score 2):

You might want to read about [Maven Dependency scopes](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Dependencies). The default scope is `compile` and you should not change that unless you absolutely must.

> - **compile** - this is the default scope, used if none is specified. Compile dependencies are available in all classpaths.
> - **runtime** - this scope indicates that the dependency is not required for compilation, but is for execution. It is in the runtime and test classpaths, but not the compile classpath.

---

The easiest way to run some class in your project is to use the [`exec-maven-plugin`](http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/index.html).

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
            <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>java</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <mainClass>com.example.Main</mainClass>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Now you can run the project like this:

```
mvn package exec:java
```

That is easy and you don't have to think about the classpath setup.